# modal/Dialog not applying match parent layout on width

Tags: android, android-layout, modal-dialog, android-linearlayout, android-dialog

I have a dialog/modal that I need to match_parent along its width. However, it keeps doing wrap_content. Any ideas how to rectify this?

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#55555555" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onDogsClicked"
            android:text="Dogs" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Cats"
            android:text="Cat" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/snake"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onSnakeClicked"
            android:text="Snake" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sheep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onSheepClicked"
            android:text="Sheep" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the program fragment

```
Dialog animalsView;

    public void onAnimalsClicked(View v) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animals_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_root));

        animalsView = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = animalsView.getWindow()
            .getAttributes();

        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        wmlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        animalsView.getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);

        animalsView.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        animalsView.setContentView(dialoglayout);
        animalsView.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        animalsView.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find a solution for doing it in the XML. But there is a solution in the .java file.

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = animalsView.getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    params.height = 100;
    params.width = android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public void onAnimalsClicked(View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animals_layout,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_root));

    animalsView = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog);

    ........

    animalsView.setContentView(dialoglayout);

    animalsView.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ......

    animalsView.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this. I was working with an overlay when I faced this issue. Hope this helps you.

```
 Dialog animalsView;

    public void onAnimalsClicked(View v) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animals_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_root));

        animalsView = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        wmlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        animalsView.getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);

        animalsView.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        animalsView.setContentView(dialoglayout);
        animalsView.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        animalsView.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got similar issue and went through tons of StackOverflow posts concerning this issue.

I tried all possible solutions (changing layout configuration of the dialog window in all possible ways mostly), but none of them works.

However, when comparing the XML layout of a dialog for which the `match_parent` worked and the XML layout of dialog for which it does not, I finally found a weird way to make it work:

I have to set the `layout_height` of the dialog to `match_parent` as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // ...

</LinearLayout>
```

My guess is that when it comes to Dialogs, Android tries to maintain the minimum possible ratio between height and width. When the `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`, then this ratio is bounded by the height and the width is shrunk.
But by switching to `match_parent` for the `layout_height`, then the ratio is bigger and bounded that the width that now fills the entire screen.
Not sure if that's the correct explanation, but that's what I deduce from this observation.
Even though this is counter-intuitive, that may sound logical in that way...

Also, I tried on both landscape and portrait, both works after this change.

Finally, note that I have strictly nothing related to window configuration in my java code:

```
    final Dialog dialogLayout = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialogLayout.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogLayout.setCancelable(false);

    View layout = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_dialog_introduce_myself, null);
    dialogLayout.setContentView(layout);
    //  ...
    dialogLayout.show();
```